# Using Julia's dot notation and in place operation

Tags: julia, in-place, elementwise-operations

How do I use both Julia's dot notation to do elementwise operations AND ensure that the result is saved in an already existing array?

```
function myfun(x, y)
    return x + y
end

a = myfun(1, 2)  # Results in a == 3

a = myfun.([1 2], [3; 4])  # Results in a == [4 5; 5 6]

function myfun!(x, y, out)
    out .= x + y
end

a = zeros(2, 2)
myfun!.([1 2], [3; 4], a)  # Results in a DimensionMismatch error
```

Also, does `@. a = myfun([1 2], [3; 4])` write the result to `a` in the same way as I am trying to achieve with `myfun!()`? That is, does that line write the result directly to `a` without saving storing the result anywhere else first?

Comment: `out` should preferably be the first parameter, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Write-functions-with-argument-ordering-similar-to-Julia-Base.

Comment: If your function is 'inherently scalar', i.e. is most naturally expressed as a scalar function (as in your example), then the most idiomatic approach is to _not_ define `myfun!`, but instead use the `a .= myfun.(x, y)` alternative. Making a `myfun!` is what you would do if it's difficult or awkward to achieve in-place operations otherwise, which is not the case here. Then you push the broadcasting to a higher level, rather then a lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
julia> function myfun!(x, y, out)
           out .= x .+ y
       end
myfun! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myfun!([1 2], [3; 4], a)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.0  5.0
 5.0  6.0

julia> a
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.0  5.0
 5.0  6.0
```

As for `@. a = myfun([1 2], [3; 4])` - the answer is yes, it does not create temporary arrays and operates in-place.

Comment: I infer that it is not possible to do what I am trying to: that is, to treat the `out` argument in the same element-wise fashion as the `x` and `y` arguments when doing in-place operations. Is this correct?

Comment: When you write `myfun!.([1 2], [3; 4], a)` you do not pass `a` to `myfun!` but only its elements. Does this clarify your issue?

Comment: Yes, it does :-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't commonly required, and there are usually better ways to achieve this, but it's possible to broadcast on an output argument by using `Ref`erence values that point inside the output array.

```
julia> a = zeros(2, 2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> function myfun!(out, x, y)
          out[] = x + y
       end
myfun! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myfun!.((Ref(a, i) for i in LinearIndices(a)), [1 2], [3; 4])
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  5
 5  6

julia> a
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.0  5.0
 5.0  6.0
```

*Edit*: Changed `out` to be the first parameter as per the [Style guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Write-functions-with-argument-ordering-similar-to-Julia-Base) - thanks to @phipsgabler for the reminder.